# Give only execute permissions to a Linux binary (prevent inspection)?

Tags: linux, permissions, binary-code

I'm writing an assignment for a security course, and I'm trying to create an executable which students can interact with (ie, execute), but not inspect. In particular what I'd like is for them to be able to execute the binary but not be able to inspect its contents in any way - reading the file, attaching a debugger, etc.

From trial and error, it seems as though giving "other" only execute permission, non-owners of the file are able to execute but not read or attach a debugger (including by attaching to it after it's running - it's actually ptrace that gives the error, so I'm convinced that it's not just gdb failing to read the associated binary file). My question is: am I right about this? Is giving students only execute permissions actually sufficient? To be concrete, they're asked to crack encryption, and the key is stored in the binary, so if they can inspect the binary in any capacity (including the process' memory), they'll be able to sidestep the challenge of the assignment.

Comment: Off Topic: Not a real life scenario in my opinion. In addition to that, it's a bad practice to store the encryption key in the executable. I'm not seeing the actual point is such an assignment, perhaps you can elaborate on that.

Comment: if your students can extract the key from the executable and use it to decrypt the cyphertext ..... win?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox for me this is a fairly common scenario... but then again I'm in teaching too :-)

Comment: Suggestion: make a web application that performs the same function. Handle the secret parts on the back end so that (assuming security) the process cannot be inspected at all. This would solve most of your problems.

Comment: @korockinout13: If I wanted to go that route, I'd just setuid the binaries (which I know is a viable option - just one I'd rather avoid).

Comment: You can't easily guarantee a clean execution environment if you let your untrusted users execute themselves, sadly. suid/sgid binaries (to a specific, dedicated identity) are a viable option in my book for your kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer as I've got little time...

Your approach would prevent plain reading of the file but students could still cheat, e.g. by `LD_PRELOAD`ing, and changing any of your internal functions to literally print the stack/heap on screen. You must prevent changes to the environment as well (you can unset `LD_PRELOAD` as a first thing in your `main()`).

Students could also `strace` your program, and that might or might not reveal internal strings depending on the system calls you make with them. However, according to [Gilles' comment on this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-analyse-an-executable-with-no-read-permission), `strace` will not honour `suid`/`sgid` bits when executing.

To prevent both `gdb`/`ptrace` attaching and `strace`, you can make the program `suid`/`sgid` to a specific identity that has access to a file `chmod`ed to 400. This will mean that the executable must be run with that `suid` identity to access the secret. In fact, if I remember well, `LD_PRELOAD` should also be ignored by `suid` binaries.

You can easily verify this by building a program that prints the results of `geteuid()` and `getuid()` and run it, `chown`ed to root and with the `setuid` bit, both normally and with `strace`.